# Converting list in list to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I got a list like this:

```
[['a','b','1','2']['c','d','3','4']]
```

and I want to convert this list to dictionary something looks like this:

```
{
    ('a','b'):('1','2'),
    ('c','d'):('3','4')
}
```

for example, ('a', 'b') & ('c','d') for key 
and ('1','2') &('3','4') for value

so I used code something like this

```
new_dict = {}
for i, k in enumerate(li[0:2]):
    new_dict[k] =[x1[i] for x1 in li[2:]]
print(new_dict)
```

,but it caused unhashable type error 'list'

I tried several other way, but it didn't work well.. 
Is there any way that I can fix it?

Comment: why don't you first iterate through the list to get each list by it self ?

Comment: If you put the result you want to obtain on the console, you get an error (dict of dict): `{{('a','b'):('1','2')},{('c','d'):('3','4')}}`. Maybe you want to achieve this instead? `[{('a','b'):('1','2')},{('c','d'):('3','4')}]` (list of dict)

Comment: @Andrea This one is what I wanted just miss understood question. {('a','b'):('1','2'), ('c','d'):('3','4')}

Comment: First of all the input list lacks a comma.

Comment: @goldenasian Please edit your question, `{('a','b'):('1','2'), ('c','d'):('3','4')}` is different from `{{('a','b'):('1','2')}, {('c','d'):('3','4')}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have `list` as key, but `tuple` is possible. Also you don't need to slice on your list,  but on the sublist.

You need  the 2 first values `sublist[:2]` as key and the corresponding values is the sublist from index 2 `sublist[2:]`

```
new_dict = {}
for sublist in li:
    new_dict[tuple(sublist[:2])] = tuple(sublist[2:])

print(new_dict)  # {('a', 'b'): ('1', '2'), ('c', 'd'): ('3', '4')}
```

The same with dict comprehension

```
new_dict = {tuple(sublist[:2]): tuple(sublist[2:]) for sublist in li}
print(new_dict)  # {('a', 'b'): ('1', '2'), ('c', 'd'): ('3', '4')}
```

Comment: I'd forgot that tuple is usable for key thank you think this is most efficient way to do it thank you.

Comment: @goldenasian No prob, You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `list`-comprehension following way:

```
lst = [['a','b','1','2']['c','d','3','4']]
dct = dict([(tuple(i[:2]),tuple(i[2:])) for i in lst])
print(dct)
```

or alternatively `dict`-comprehension:

```
dct = {tuple(i[:2]):tuple(i[2:]) for i in lst}
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'b'): ('1', '2'), ('c', 'd'): ('3', '4')}
```

Note that `list` slicing produce `list`s, which are mutable and can not be used as `dict` keys, so I use `tuple` to convert these to immutable tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
li = [['a','b','1','2'],['c','d','3','4']]
new_dict = {}
for item in li:
    new_dict[(item[0], item[1])] = (item[2], item[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dict comprehension:

```
li = [
    ['a', 'b', '1', '2'],
    ['c', 'd', '3', '4'],
]

new_dict = {(i[0], i[1]): (i[2], i[3]) for i in li}

print(new_dict)


# result
{('a', 'b'): ('1', '2'), ('c', 'd'): ('3', '4')}
```

Comment: There is no explanation at all about why the OP's code is not valid, what solution you propose, to avoid people querying just code, answer shouldn't just give code ;)

Comment: I see, I'll improve my answers next time. Thanks for the tip @azro