# converting dictionary containing tuple to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I made a dictionary from textfile:

```
{('Aaronsburg', 'PA'): ('40.9184', '-77.3786'), ('Abbeville', 'AL'): 
 ('31.5951', '-85.2108'), ('Abbeville', 'GA'): ('31.9890', '-83.3217'),
 ('Abbeville', 'LA'): ('29.9124', '-92.2110'), ('Abbeville', 'MS'): 
 ('34.4771', '-89.4450'), ('Abbeville', 'SC'): ('34.1621', '-82.4333')}
```

These are sample from original text file:

```
  Aaronsburg,PA,40.9184,-77.3786
  Abbeville,AL,31.5951,-85.2108
```

and want to change all the tuple inside dictionary to dictionary like this:

```
{{'Aaronsburg', 'PA'}: {'40.9184', '-77.3786'}, {'Abbeville', 'AL'}: 
 {'31.5951', '-85.2108'}, {'Abbeville', 'GA'}: {'31.9890', '-83.3217'}, 
 {'Abbeville', 'LA'}: {'29.9124', '-92.2110'}, {'Abbeville', 'MS'}: 
 {'34.4771', '-89.4450'}, {'Abbeville', 'SC'}: {'34.1621', '-82.4333'}}
```

but, got stuck while doing that....

This is original code till get dictionary

```
def coordinates(txt):
  d = []
  with open(txt) as f:
       for line in f:
           d.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
  new_dict = {}
  for sublist in d:
      new_dict[tuple(sublist[:2])] = tuple(sublist[2:])
  return((new_dict))
```

Comment: The keys need to **immutable** and dictionaries are mutable. So, not possible in Python.

Comment: Then is there any other way to change original text file to {{a, b}:{1,2},{c:d}:{3:4}} format?

Comment: And `{'Aaronsburg', 'PA'}` is called a set....`{'Aaronsburg':'PA'}` is called a dictionary...You want the keys to be sets or dictionaries? The same goes to values too

Comment: Yes, so I tried new_d = dict(set(k), set(v)) for k, v in new_dict.items()), but error has occurred

Comment: Check the answer I posted. ;)

Comment: @goldenasian, this looks like XY problem and maybe you are confused [especially, given your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882390/converting-list-in-list-to-dictionary). What is your actual goal/problem you have to solve?

Comment: my goal is to make def call coordinates that return a dictionary that maps each city onto its coordinate (b,l).   
something like this   

>>> coordinate = coordinates('cities.txt')

>>> coordinate['Dalhart,TX'] 

(36.1173, -102.6024)

the code working on pycharm, but it cause key error when I make submission to website (KeyError: 'Dalhart,TX')

Comment: So this in fact homework question, I guess. You may as well post the exact assignment. As you can see from error, the key it is looking for is a string, i.e. if I am right you need to combine City and state in a single string key, separated by comma.

Comment: Think that will solve my problem thank you so much, I will do some more research on basic stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary keys need to be ***immutable***. So, you can use `frozenset` instead of a `set` for keys and use `set` for values.

```
{frozenset(k):set(v) for k,v  in my_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{frozenset({'Aaronsburg', 'PA'}): {'-77.3786', '40.9184'},
 frozenset({'AL', 'Abbeville'}): {'-85.2108', '31.5951'},
 frozenset({'Abbeville', 'GA'}): {'-83.3217', '31.9890'},
 frozenset({'Abbeville', 'LA'}): {'-92.2110', '29.9124'},
 frozenset({'Abbeville', 'MS'}): {'-89.4450', '34.4771'},
 frozenset({'Abbeville', 'SC'}): {'-82.4333', '34.1621'}}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, but thank you for your kindness I will keep try, I might be misunderstood original question

Answer (score 1):

I think what your are trying to do is not possible, as a key cannot be from a mutable type. Reading python dictionary documentation [dictionary documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any **immutable type**; strings and numbers can always be keys. Tuples can be used as keys if they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples; if a tuple contains any mutable object either directly or indirectly, it cannot be used as a key. You can’t use lists as keys, since lists can be modified in place using index assignments, slice assignments, or methods like append() and extend().